# Let $\gcd(m,n)=1$, prove that $m\mathbb Z/mn\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $\gcd(m,n)=1$, prove that $m\mathbb Z/mn\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$

Comment: Try the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Let's see, how could we devise a surjective homomorphism $m\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z_n$ with kernel $mn\Bbb Z$? Would $mk \mapsto [k]_n$ work?